# chrome history db access is locked

Tags: python, sqlite, google-chrome

I am creating an application where I need to access chrome's history but whenever i try to connect with that history db i get the following error:
*c.execute(sql)
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked*

here is the code:

```
 `data_path = os.path.expanduser('~')+"/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default"
files = os.listdir(data_path)
history_db = os.path.join(data_path, 'history')
conn = sqlite3.connect(history_db)
c = conn.cursor()
sql = "SELECT url FROM urls"
c.execute(sql)`
```

Comment: Chrome is open, try closing it before accessing the sqlite3 db.

Comment: Thanks, @pedro lobito it helped

Comment: I'll post answer that you can accept if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> c.execute(sql) sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked

This error occurs when you try to access the `sqlite3` `db` while `chrome` is **running**. You should close it **before** accessing the `db`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way around this if you dont want to close your browser is to simply copy the history data into new location and then read it.
here is the code:

```
import sqlite3
import shutil

source_file = 'C:\\Users\\{username}\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\History'
destination_file = 'C:\\Users\\{username}\\Downloads\\History'

time.sleep(30)# wait to update the history file
shutil.copy(source_file,destination_file)
con = sqlite3.connect('C:\\Users\\{username}\\Downloads\\History')
cursor = con.execute("SELECT * FROM urls")
```

Now you can see the Chrom browser history without closing your Chrom Browser.